# Is there a way to convince Emacs 29 to use the initial directory to save setup information?

Tags: init-file, load-path, version-compatibilty

One of the powerful features of Emacs is that you can change almost any of its settings using provided interactive dialogs.

With the in version 29 provided possibility to specify a directory to load initial files from I have expected that I will be able to use multiple Emacs versions and keep them apart by running them with different specified paths to the initialization files.

But it seems not to work as I expected because Emacs 29 still saves interactively changed options to the standard .emacs file in the users home directory.

Have I overseen something? *Is there a way to convince Emacs 29 it should not only load initialization files from a specified directory but also save all of the interactively changed settings there?*

Comment: `C-h v custom-file` maybe?

Comment: @NickD : `custom-file` looks promising, but I haven't yet evaluated it. It's time-consuming to check all the possible cases to see if and how it works. In between I consider even to give up on the idea to run multiple versions because of the possibility of unpredictable and not directly apparent side-effects and because there is no answer to my question yet.

Comment: Is there anyone here running multiple Emacs versions keeping all their settings apart? If yes, please respond and share how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up your `load-path` conditionally, in your init file. Have it use different directories for different Emacs versions. Just test `emacs-version` or any of the other variables provided for this -- see (elisp) [Version Info](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Version-Info.html).

And see (elisp) [Library Search](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Search.html) for info about `load-path`.

---

Wrt your comment asking about Customize and your saved settings from it:

I recommend you *always* use a separate `custom-file`, and *not let Customize mess with your hand-coded init file.*

Your init file can conditionally set variable `custom-file` to different files, depending on the Emacs version (or whatever else). Then when you use Customize (or its functions) in a given Emacs version and you save changes, they'll be saved to the right `custom-file`.

Comment: Does this setting also solve the problem of the target file used for saving interactively with Custom changed settings which is by default ~/.emacs? Are there maybe also other side-effects I am not yet aware of like this just mentioned to take care about?

Comment: I recommend you always use a separate `custom-file`, and not let Customize mess with your hand-coded init file. Your init file can conditionally set variable `custom-file` to different files. Then when you use Customize (or its functions) in a given Emacs version and you save changes, they'll be saved to the right `custom-file`.